# Git-ignore certain files in sub-directories, but not all

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a structure similar to the following:

```
/root/
/root/data/
/root/data/script.php
/root/data/some.json
/root/data/feature/one.json
/root/data/feature/two.json
/root/data/other-feature/one.json
/root/data/other-feature/important-script.php
```

I'd like git to ignore *any* `.json` files under the '/data/...' path, but '/data/' sometimes contains sub-directories.

My understanding is that a simple `data/*.json` in gitignore will only match one directory, as the `*` doesn't match `/`, as stated at http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore, "Pattern Format", bullet #6:

> Otherwise, git treats the pattern as a shell glob suitable for consumption by fnmatch(3) with the FNM_PATHNAME flag: wildcards in the pattern will not match a / in the pathname. For example, "Documentation/*.html" matches "Documentation/git.html" but not "Documentation/ppc/ppc.html" or "tools/perf/Documentation/perf.html".

Is there a simple way to do this, or do I need to actively add gitignore files in each sub-directory, explicitly?

Comment: Most up to date answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10714272/176877

Answer (score 116, accepted):

I've written a post about such problem recently. See [here](http://sparethought.wordpress.com/2011/07/19/double-star-pattern-in-gitignore/).

Basically what you need is to put one `.gitignore` with `*.json` in the `/data/` directory.

**UPD**: Since git [1.8.4](http://git-blame.blogspot.com/2013/08/git-184.html) ([1.8.2](https://github.com/msysgit/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.2.txt) if you're using msysgit) it is possible to use double-star patterns, like `/data/**/*.json`

Comment: I added the `.gitignore` file, containing `*.json`, but if I change one of those files, and run `git status`, I see them listed as "Changes not staged". Do `.gitignore` files need to committed before taking effect? Is this showing up because the files were previously tracked?

Comment: Previously tracked files will be tracked no matter what is in `.gitignore`

Comment: Back up a file you want to stop tracking, then try `git rm --cached <file>`. This will remove the file from remote, while `--cached` will retain it locally. I think the file will no longer appear under "Changes not staged." If that works, you can do the same for all others: `git rm --cached <file list>`.

Comment: If you want to ignore **all except php**, you need `/data/**/*.*` followed by `/data/**/*.php`.

Comment: @MarkLoyman I guess you meant "followed by `!/data/**/*.php`" to un-ignore php files back.

Answer (score 26):

you can place `data/**/*.json` in your `.gitignore` in `/root` directory to prevent multiple `.gitignore` files in different directories

`**/` - matches any count of subdirectories (including current)

example: `data/**/*.json` record will ignore `data/1.json`, `data/subfolder/2.json`, `data/../../3.json`

Comment: @CaptainBlammo I'm using it, it works, may be you did somthing wrong?

there is info: [some docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: and it will also ignore `/bla/data/**/*.json` and `/bla/bla/data/**/*.json`. `/data/**/*.json` should be used.

Answer (score 6):

This pattern work for me for data subfolder ignoring only png and jpg files:

```
**/data/**/*.png
**/data/**/*.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick Answer

```
# ignore all nested json file
/**/*.json
```