# gitignore files with extension in folder

Tags: wildcard, gitignore, subdirectory

I'm trying to make git ignore all files with extension .ex but only if they are in a subfolder with the name subf. In man gitignore I read the following:

```
Two consecutive asterisks ("**") in patterns matched against full pathname may have special meaning:

   ·   A leading "**" followed by a slash means match in all directories. For example, "**/foo" matches file or directory "foo" anywhere, the same as pattern "foo". "**/foo/bar" matches file or
       directory "bar" anywhere that is directly under directory "foo".
```

However, if I put my `**/subf/*.ex` into `.gitignore` (in repository base directory) my files with `.ex` extension are not ignored! I read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712555/gitignore-all-files-of-extension-in-directory) thread that I should add my exclusion rule to the file `.git/info/exclude`. This seems to work for me but I'm not happy with it since this is not how I understood `.gitignore`. Can somebody help me understand why putting `**/subf/*.ex` does not work in `.gitignore`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

why not as simple as,

```
 subf/*.ex
```

Or if you are expecting subf at any level,

```
**/subf/*.ex
```

It is working for me