# Gitignore multiple project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xcode, git, gitignore

I have a master directory which contains 2 subdirectories:

- 1 iOS project
- 1 rails project

How can I ignore both these gitignores without having only one gitignore in the master directory as:

```
*.rbc
capybara-*.html
.rspec
/log
/tmp
/db/*.sqlite3
/db/*.sqlite3-journal
/public/system
/coverage/
/spec/tmp
**.orig
rerun.txt
pickle-email-*.html

## Environment normalisation:
/.bundle
/vendor/bundle

# these should all be checked in to normalise the environment:
# Gemfile.lock, .ruby-version, .ruby-gemset

# unless supporting rvm < 1.11.0 or doing something fancy, ignore this:
.rvmrc

# if using bower-rails ignore default bower_components path bower.json files
/vendor/assets/bower_components
*.bowerrc
bower.json

# Ignore pow environment settings
.powenv

# sublime text
*.sublime-*


# Xcode

.DS_Store
*/build/*
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode*
!default.mode*
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
xcuserdata
profile
*.moved-aside
DerivedData
.idea/
*.hmap
*.xcworkspace
*.xcuserdata

#CocoaPods

Pods/
Podfile.lock
```

But it does not seem to well ignore my configuration, I want to avoid this:

```
# Xcode

mystore-ios/.DS_Store
mystore-ios/*/build/*
mystore-ios/*.pbxuser
mystore-ios/!default.pbxuser
mystore-ios/*.mode*
mystore-ios/!default.mode*
mystore-ios/*.perspectivev3
mystore-ios/!default.perspectivev3
mystore-ios/xcuserdata
mystore-ios/profile
```

How can I do?

Comment: Why don't you place a .gitignore in every projectfolder?

Comment: You can use wildcards for subdirectories
It is answered in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545602/git-ignore-sub-folders

Answer (score 1):

.gitignore works in subdirectories so you can do:

```
master_directory/ios_project/.gitignore
master_directory/rails_project/.gitignore
```

These .gitignore files will override any .gitignore files from parent directories.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this but .gitignore supports `**` syntax as of version `1.8.2.1` to match and ignore through subdirectories. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712555/gitignore-all-files-of-extension-in-directory/21147445#21147445) in another question may be of use.