# Git ignore jpg in all directories besides one

Tags: pattern-matching, gitignore, glob

I want to modify my `.gitignore` so I can ignore all `.jpg` files which aren't in `/public/assets/images`.

I have tried the following:

```
(!/public/assets/images/)!*.jpg

/public/assets/images/!*.jpg
```

However besides those two I am not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try ignoring all jpg files, then explicitly unignoring `/public/assets/images`:

```
**/*.jpg
!/public/assets/images/*.jpg
```

The following answers explore this tangentially, and may be useful:

- [How do I tell Git to ignore everything except a subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248570/how-do-i-tell-git-to-ignore-everything-except-a-subdirectory)
- [gitignore all files of extension in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712555/gitignore-all-files-of-extension-in-directory)