# Gitignore - how to exclude files of specific extension in a specific directory?

Tags: git

I am wondering how to exclude specific files' type in git. For example: I am writing code under a directory using TypeScript. Files are getting rendered to .js extension. I have some other directories with .js files that I would like to commit. But, for example, in folder `common` I would like to to have all compiled files excluded from git tracking. I don't wanna to see them in a console.
How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Am surprised you have not researched hard enough to read up on [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gitignore all files of extension in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712555/gitignore-all-files-of-extension-in-directory)

Comment: I have added `*.js` in .gitignore file but still displaing `js` extension file in `git status` comment. Any other solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a .gitignore file at `common/.gitignore` and then add this rule, this will omit all .js files within your common directory:

```
*.js
```

Comment: I have added `*.js` in .gitignore file but still displaing `js` extension file in `git status` comment. Any other solution? Thanks.