# .gitignore un-ignore .cc files

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a `.gitignore` file in which I ignore everything, and then un-ignore specific files and directories. However, one part of it doesn't seem to work.

```
/*

!.gitignore
!Makefile
!include/
!src/
!test/*.cc

**.swp
```

New `*.cc` files in the `test` directory don't appear in `git status`.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712555/gitignore-all-files-of-extension-in-directory) seems keen on having you create a `.gitignore` for your specific subfolder.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I made `test/.gitignore` with `*.cc` but the result is exactly the same.

Comment: What version of Git are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/*` rule causes the `test` directory to be ignored, so git never descends into it at all. Therefore your `!test/*.cc` rule has no effect.

You need a sequence of alternating and overlapping rules like this: ignore everything, then un-ignore `test`, then ignore everything under `test`, then un-ignore the `.cc` files within `test`.

```
/*
!test
test/*
!test/*.cc
```

Comment: I guess a directory doesn't come along for the ride with the pattern that can't be matched without it.