# Preceding `/` preventing gitignore exceptions from working for file extension exclusion

Tags: git, gitignore

```
*.dll

!/ThirdPartyLibraries/*.dll
!/ThirdPartyLibraries/*/*.dll
!/ThirdPartyLibraries/*/lib/*.dll
!/ThirdPartyLibraries/*/lib/*/*.dll
```

I am trying to include dlls only from that folder but it won't let me

I searched and I searched all I found was directory ignores then directory exceptions which doesn't apply here

if this has been asked before, please forgive my search skills

Comment: FYI I already fixed it by removing the ignore of `*.dll` and since i had bin folders ignored there was a few files I need to ignore

Comment: have a look in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712555/gitignore-all-files-of-extension-in-directory)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gitignore all files of extension in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712555/gitignore-all-files-of-extension-in-directory)

Comment: are there other folders in `ThirdpartyLibraries/*/` in which you would want the dlls to be included?

Comment: @NicoAlbers Yes inside there are several folders, 1 for each 3rd part lib we have in our roject

Comment: I read the answer you referenced and all answers on that question and i had already tried double * previously before posting my answer

Comment: Hmmm... Please edit your question and point more detailed out, why it is not enough to do `ThirdPartyLibraries/**/*.dll`?

Comment: @NicoAlbers You were right that worked, what I tried was `!/ThirdPartyLibraries/**/*.dll`  but when I tried `!ThirdPartyLibraries/**/*.dll` it worked, can you put that as an answer so I can select it as the correct one ?

Comment: Yeah, sure I'll do! What is the difference in the codes you wrote there? I can't see right now what the wrong one should be

Comment: the `/` in the beginning after `!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like we discussed in the comments, you can just type `ThirdPartyLibraries/**/*.dll` as suggested [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712555/gitignore-all-files-of-extension-in-directory).

Happy that it worked!

Comment: Thank you so much, I had begun to lose confidence in `git` :O :O, confidence restored!