# Git ignore subfolders but not the files in a folder

Tags: git, gitignore

I've been looking around and just could not find the same scenario that I have. I have:

```
--public
      |--img
           |--logo (folder)
           |--post_image (folder)
           |--banner.jpg
           |--icon.ico
           |--image1.jpg
           |-........etc
```

I need to ignore the `logo` and `post_image` folders, but I want to keep every file that is inside `img` folder. How would I go about it?

Right now I have `**/public/img` but I feel is not the right approach!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I found this to be simpler (at least in the case there are many subfolders):

```
public/img/*/
```

This will exclude all subfolders in `public/img/`, but will not exclude the files in this folder.

Comment: This did not seem to work for me.  added a hidden file to each directory and only want subdirectories ignored, but /folder/subfolder/*/ is still ignoring subfolder.

Comment: @rippledj I don't quite understand what you mean. `/folder/subfolder/*/` will not ignore `/folder/subfolder/`, but each directory inside. What do you the hidden files expect to change?

Comment: So, I think my mistake was that I wanted to keep the empty folders in the repo (diff than OP goal).  So, I thought that /folder/subfolder/*/ would keep the folder if I just put an empty hidden file inside.  However, it was the same as ignoring all the folder contents. I needed a different solution. (!/folder/.keep).

Answer (score 8):

You can put a `.gitignore` file into any child directory, it doesn't have to be at the root. In your case, a `.gitignore` file in the `public/img` directory with the content:

```
logo
post_image
```

would do the job.

For another approaches, you might want to look at:

- [gitignore all files of extension in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712555/gitignore-all-files-of-extension-in-directory/)
- [Git-ignore certain files in sub-directories, but not all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794717/git-ignore-certain-files-in-sub-directories-but-not-all)

Comment: Is it also possible to do it from the root directory? Like have a .gitignore file in the root with `/img/logo` and `/img/post-Image`? Is there a difference if I do it from the root directory or straight from the child directories?

Comment: Actually I want to ignore all subfolders but not files. In the OPs that would mean I don't want to specific `logo` and `post_image` specifically because if I add another folder and forget it won't be ignored. Is there a way to specify ignore all subfolders but not files in a specific folder?  In other words `dist/foo.txt` yes, `dist/someFolder` no

Answer (score 2):

Please try below options .

```
public/img/*

!public/img/logo/

!public/img/post_image/
```

[git-ignore](https://github.com/git/git/blob/59856de171397c355923ee6cd6debae89385c824/Documentation/gitignore.txt)