# Why doesn't this ignore my files recursively?

Tags: gitignore

In my project's root directory there are directories like 'tools':

```
tools/evaluate/test/
tools/evaluate2
```

Under test, there are some .py and .csv files. I want to ignore all files except .py, so in my .gitignore, I have this entry:

```
!tools/**/*.py
```

I want to recursively ignore all non-python files under tools. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Have you already committed some of those non-py files previously?

Comment: I think you may have just forgotten a slash after the bang. Possible duplicate of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794717/git-ignore-certain-files-in-sub-directories-but-not-all)

Comment: @BeRT2me Yes. Some py files are already in the repository.

Comment: !/tools/**/*.py: This doesn't work either. @JohnAlexINL

Comment: @marlon I asked about the NON-PY files, not the PY files.

Comment: `!tools/**/*.py` only means "but keep the .py files". You have to have a rule to exclude that place before it. https://github.com/kenmueller/gitignore#everything-inside-of-a-folder-except-for-some-files

Comment: @BeRT2me I might have committed some csv files before, but today I added two new csv files and want to ignore them. Also, I checked the directory in remote git repository, there is only one .sh file and all others are .py files.

Answer (score 1):

if the files you are trying to ignore have been already committed, you need to remove them from the staging area as well, that's done by:

```
git rm --cached !tools/**/*.py
```

check the status:

```
git status
```

add the files you want to delete to `.gitignore` i assume manually, i don't know of an automatic way, then finally:

```
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "Remove unused files"
```

Comment: No. Not committed.

Comment: any errors along the way?

Comment: No errors. Just not ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Two parts are needed here:

```
# Recursively ignore everything in tools that has an extension:
**/tools/**/*.*

# Except .py files recursively in tools:
!tools/**/*.py
```